# Simple Timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I have this code

```
private void picTop_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (timer1.Tick == 10)
  {
    picBottom.Visible = true;
    picTop.Visible = false;
    timer1.Stop();
  }
  else 
  {
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR You cannot view this section at this time.\nPlease try again later.");
  }
}

private void picBottom_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  picBottom.Visible = false;
  picTop.Visible = true;
  timer1.Start();
}
```

My timerinterval is set at 1000ms (so 1 second)
I only want the user to go into the top panel again after 10 seconds.
Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Current error I get: timer1.Tick is red underlined, error=
"The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Tick' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

Answer (score 2):

`Timer.Tick` is not property its an event.

Use it like

```
timer1.Tick += 
{
    picBottom.Visible = true;
    picTop.Visible = false;
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

For interval use `timer.Interval`

```
timer.Interval = 10000;
```

Comment: Fine answer, but should be 10000.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think I understand what you're trying to achieve...

You have 2 areas on your form called "Top" & "Bottom"

Once the user enters & subsequently leaves the top area, you don't want them to be able to enter again for 10 seconds. is that correct?

So you've got a few problems... first of all, `Tick` is an event to which you would attach a method to be fired when it is raised. it's not an integer you can check. The only integer property on a timer of relevance for timing for is called `Interval`

But aside from that I don't think your method is going to be particularly effective.
Perhaps a better idea would be to add a `MouseExit` event to the top area. and disable that area for 10 seconds. and use a timer to re-enable it.

```
timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;

public void Top_MouseExit (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PicTop.Visible = false; // or hide/disbale it some other way
   Timer1.Interval = 10000; //10 seconds
   Timer1.Start();
}

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    PicTop.Visible = true; //renable the top area
}
```

Comment: Correct, but it only needs to display if the user enters the top area again, it doesn't need to auto display again. The user should be forced to wait 10 seconds before switching views again (only one half visible at once)